# How to add values at JSONObject in Java?

Tags: java, json

I added values using like `json.put("key", "value")`.

The result was `{"key": "value"}`.

But I want to get result like `{key: "value"}`

How do I do?

Comment: When you print JSON both keys and values will have quotes around them. Thus if you would search your JSONobject for *key* you would get the value, and searching for *"key"* would return null/throw exception

Comment: What you want is not a valid JSON. and btw where you need this type of requirement ?

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible as JSON Objects' keys are always enclosed in quotes. The values can have no quotes if it's Booloean or number like :

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "isAlive": true,
  "age": 25,
  "height_cm": 167.6
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Json uses quotes to increase the posible types of key and value.

Example:

> { Some key : Some Vaue } - Invalid
>
> { Some key : Some : Vaue } - Invalid

This is not a valid JSON as any Json parser will fail to identify the "space" between words. In order to avoid such situations, JSON objects are defined with quotes.

> { "Some key" : "Some : Vaue" } - This is valid

This is the reason for any JSON parser to return the key and values quoted.

An example to help you

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        
        //String json = "{key : \"value\"}"; - Valid
        
        //String json = "{key : value}"; - Valid
        
        //String json = "{key : some : value}"; // Invalid

        String json = "{key : \"some : value\"}"; // Valid
        
        Map<String, String>  map = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);
        
        System.out.println(map.size());
        
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(map));
        
    }
```